# Why do we need finite dimension for this diagram to commute?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\frak g$ be a Lie algebra and $\rho$ be a finite dimensional representation of $\frak g$ in a linear space $V$. They define the *momentum* associated to $\rho$ as the map $\mu: V \otimes V^\ast \to {\frak g}^\ast$ given by $\mu(v \otimes \phi)(x) = \phi(\rho(x)(v))$. Then we're asked to check that $\mu$ interchanges $\rho \otimes \rho^\ast$ with ${\rm ad}^\ast$. in other words, that for all $x \in {\frak g}$ we have this commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    V \otimes V^\ast @>\mu>> {\frak g}^\ast\\
    @A {(\rho \otimes \rho^\ast)(x)} A A @AA {\rm ad}^\ast(x) A\\
    V \otimes V^\ast @>>\mu> {\frak g}^\ast
    \end{CD}

I managed to check that the diagram commutes (just keep a level head and do it), but I don't see why do we need $\dim V < \infty$ here. My first thought would be that $\mu$ would be an isomorphism in that case, but we don't know anything about the dimension of ${\frak g}$, so I guess we can discard that.

(Here $\rho \otimes \rho^\ast$ is a shorthand for $\rho \otimes {\rm id}_{V^\ast}+{\rm id}_{V}\otimes \rho^\ast$)

Comment: Who is "they"? Anyway, I don't believe that you need finite-dimensionality, although it's nicer in this case because $\mu$ is then the linear dual of the action map, regarded as a map $\mathfrak{g} \to V^{\ast} \otimes V$.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. It is an exercise in San Martin's "Álgebras de Lie", but I think this book only has a portuguese edition, though.

Comment: I guess that in this San Martin's book when he says there is an exchange operator (as in the Exercise 18 of the Chapter 1) between two given representations he is not assuming that the exchange operator is a linear isomorphism. That is, an exchange operator need not o be a isomorphism of representations. I had this same doubt. But then I realized that when he introduces the term exchange operator (in page 30 of 2ed) he is more concerned in labeling the exchange operator that appears in the definition of isomorphic representations than defining a practical definition of exchange operator.

Comment: @Júlio I think I got it. Two repsentations are *equivalent* (isomorphic) in sense of page 30 if there is an exchange operator which happens to be an isomorphism, which is not necessarily the case of exercise 18 (that I asked here). Right?

Comment: @IvoTerek Exactly.